# How secure is using HTTP Basic Authentication to get JWT token?

Tags: angular, security, http-headers, jwt, basic-authentication

I'm not too familiar with HTTP Basic Authentication or web authentication in general so I would like some help in determining how secure my planned method for providing authentication for my app would be.

I plan on making an Angular app with a PHP back-end. I want to use JWT's that contain data with the logged in user's id so when HTTP requests are made, the server can determine if that user has the authorization to access specific resources.

The problem, I think, with my approach is that HTTP Basic Authentication must be first used by doing a HTTP request to log the user in, to give them a JWT token to begin with.

So if the `verify()` function in my Angular service looks like the following, and the email and password are simply base64 encoded and sent in the `Authorization` HTTP request header.

```
verify(email: string, password: string): Observable<JSON> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
        "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(email + ":" + password)
    });
    return this.http.get<JSON>("http://localhost:80/verify", { headers: headers, withCredentials: true }).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

And the HTTP request was sent over HTTPS hypothetically, how secure is that?

And if HTTPS wasn't an option and I wasn't able to get a SSL certificate, would there be any `Authorization` header types that would help my app be secure, or not?

Comment: *"would there be any Authorization header types that would help my app be secure, or not?"* No, if you're sending username and password over HTTP, then you're sending them in plaintext essentially

Comment: You don't need http basic authentication when you are using a jwt. Normally you would post your username and password as part of the body to a token endpoint which would return a jwt. You should not use http for this, only https (you should probably use https for everything tho)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing two ways to authenticate a user.

With Basic Authentication, you're supposed to send the username and password as part of every, secured, request. This doesn't use anything like a JWT token. Sending the password on every request is a security issue, this is why we're using OAuth2, which uses Bearer tokens (JWT) which we're supposed to be sending with every request.

How this works is you typically send an HTTP Post request to a specific endpoint (mostly a seperate Authentication server). The body of the request should contain the username, password and grant.

```
{
  "username": "foo",
  "password": "bar",
  "grand": "password"
}
```

This should return the JWT which you need to add as part of the Authorization header on every request:

```
"Authorization": "Bearer TOKEN_GOES_HERE"
```

You want all of this to be done over Https, definitely when you're sending the username and password to the token endpoint.

Comment: Oh ok, I guess I just wasn't sure if sending a HTTP Post request over HTTPS would be secure or not, but I guess it is. Another related question, probably a stupid one, since the Angular client will need to know what the JWT token is, to set it in the Bearer authentication scheme for every request, how should my back-end give that token to the client, via some sort of HTTP header?

Comment: The token endpoint returns the tokens as part of the body on the http post requests response. You can then save the token client side and add it to every request using an http interceptor.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _as part of the body on the http post requests response_? Does that mean to just put, in my PHP, `echo json_encode($jwt)` to return that token back to my client? And as far as saving the token client side, I probably wouldn't want to save it in localStorage or a cookie as to prevent CSRF attacks, right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, there's probably a library to handle that stuff. Generally, you do save the token in localstorage or cookies.